# How to organize binary file data into linked list?

Tags: c

I have a binary file containing fields of 5 bytes and based on the first byte read the following for will have a certain format: if the first byte is 0x55 the next 4 represent an unsigned integer and if the first byte is 0x98 the next 4 represent a 4 letter text. The program is working as intended, however I'd like to organize the data into a simply linked list but I'm having some issues. If I use `strcpy` to copy the bytes array into the linked list, how can I verify the first byte inside the switch statement? I'm not sure how to verify a *specific* member from a linked list, unlike that of an array for instance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct{
    uint8_t bytes[5]; 
}BINARY;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb"), *fout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    BINARY data;
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid format.\nCorrect usage: %s binary_file output_file.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(!fin)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file '%s' for reading.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(!fout)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file '%s' for writing.\n", argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        while(fread(&data.bytes, 5*sizeof(uint8_t), 1, fin))
        {
            switch(data.bytes[0])
            {
                case 0x55:
                    fprintf(fout, "uint : ");
                    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                    {
                        fprintf(fout, "%u", data.bytes[i]);
                    }
                    fputc('\n', fout);
                    break;
                case 0x98:
                    fprintf(fout, "text : ");
                    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
                    {
                        fprintf(fout, "%c", data.bytes[i]);
                    }
                    fputc('\n', fout);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }


    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you're not storing null terminators, `strcpy` will not work. Use `memcpy`.   But it's not entirely clear what the question is.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I forgot to mention, the letters are not null-terminated. I'm not sure how to check a specific member from the linked list

Comment: @Andrei0408 you can store data type inside LinkedList node (if you've defined a custom node type).

Comment: You don't need the outer `feof` loop at all.  Just delete it.

Comment: A linked list is not a good data structure for random access.  If you want to "check a specific member" (I'm putting that in quotes because I don't actually know what you mean), you have to walk the list to find it.  Are you just asking about storing the data type in the member of the list?